# Tailwind background color class didn't automatically compiled when using laravel component

Tags: css, tailwind-css, laravel-blade, flowbite

Hello i found its very weird that my tailwind bg color class didn't automatically compiled
It needs to be some initiation before it will compiled. I'm using vite to compiled my asset with laravel 11, tailwind 3.4 and flowbite library
Note : I already run the

> npm run dev

Here's my tailwind config :

```
export default {
    content: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
        "./resources/**/*.vue",
        "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
    ],
    darkMode: 'class',
    theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
            primary: {"50":"#eff6ff","100":"#dbeafe","200":"#bfdbfe","300":"#93c5fd","400":"#60a5fa","500":"#3b82f6","600":"#2563eb","700":"#1d4ed8","800":"#1e40af","900":"#1e3a8a","950":"#172554"}
        }
    },
    },
    plugins: [
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
}
```

Laravel blade component :

```
<button
    {{ $attributes->merge([
        'class' => 'inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 mt-4 sm:mt-6 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-'.$color.'-700 rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-'.$color.'-200 dark:focus:ring-'.$color.'-900 hover:bg-'.$color.'-800',
    ])}} >

    {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

Laravel class component :

```
{
    public $color;

    /**
     * Create the component instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        $color = 'blue'
    ) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.button');
    }
}
```

If i directly write the blade on my view like below, it won't be compiled :

```
<x-button type="button" color="red" @click="addNewRow()">+ Add Row</x-button>
```

but after i write the element without blade component, the background color will get compiled both the blade component and the regular html element

```
<button class="bg-red-700">Pink</button>

<x-button type="button" color="red" @click="addNewRow()">+ Add Row</x-button>
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind only generates the classes that are found after crawling your template files. When using dynamic classnames the finally rendered classname is not known to tailwind.

One way to solve this problem is safelisting the classnames you are building:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Comment: So it will only happened to the dynamic class which didn't explicitly written the class  right ? i mean it can't be a variable , it should be written using the intended class itself instead of php or any variable ?

Comment: Yes, Tailwind must be able to read the classname in your template. You don't have to write it inside the `class` attribute though. The classname string has somehow be in your template. Could be as a comment or you set up a variable switch with all possible color variations. Tailwind crawls all strings in your templates no matter where you put them.

Comment: Yes, i put them on variable to dynamically change the color,
Anyway your solition worked, so thanks
However i'm still curious is there any simple method instead of putting bunch of class on the config file

Comment: I guess there is no way around writing down the full readable classnames somewhere. Can be a config file (safelist) or in a file that gets crawled by Talwind. Basically you could create a file not used for your application having all the classnames in it - as long as it get crawled. I would prefer the Vite config file though.

Comment: Using regular expressions in your safelist object could be helpful if you have similar classes with variants: `https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions`

Comment: I think using the regex is more convenient, thanks for the tip